# How is this an imitation of Communist Party convention speeches?

Tags: ukrainian-language, markiyan-kamysh, stalking-the-atomic-city

Chapter 5 of *Stalking the Atomic City* contains the following quote:

> Then an hour of walking to the highway and another hour to Tamil Town Hall - a furnished building with a couch, a stove, a couple of rugs, and a guest book. Each time, I write in it, in Russian: "With thanks to Tamil Town Hall for its exemplary furnishings." I think it's a creative way of copying the style of inaugural speeches delivered at Communist Party conventions.

First, is the author old enough to even remember Communist Party conventions?

Also, why Russian? Were Communist Party conventions always held in Russian?

Finally, in what sense was this comment an imitation of these speeches?